# Iterating on an Ordered Dictionary results in: 'float' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, for-loop, ordereddictionary

I have the following function that prints out an ordered dictionary:

```
def printSQN(analyzer):
    sqn = round(analyzer.sqn, 2)
    print(f'The System Quality Number (SQN) is: {sqn}')
```

The output looks as follows:

```
OrderedDict([('sharperatio', 0.19697863771541763)])
```

I would like 'unpack' this ordered dictionary and print out only the value 0.19697863771541763.

To do so, I tried the following:

```
def printSQN(analyzer):
    sqn = round(analyzer.sqn, 2)
    for key, value in sqn.items():
        print(f'The System Quality Number (SQN) is: {value}')
```

However, running the code above results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "backtest_02a.py", line 100, in <module>
    printSQN(the_strategy.analyzers.sqn.get_analysis())
  File "backtest_02a.py", line 50, in printSQN
    for key, value in sqn.items():
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'items'
```

The docs on the `Backtrader` library say:

"The Analyzer base class creates a `self.rets` (of type `collections.OrderedDict`) member attribute to return the analysis. This is done in the method create_analysis which can be overriden by subclasses if creating custom analyzers."

It appears that my approach is the one that's suggested in the docs at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items

Does anyone see where my `for loop` is flawed?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: `print(type(sqn))` I am pretty sure it won't be `collections.OrderedDict`. That is where the problem is.

Comment: `print(type(sqn))` shows `<class 'float'>`.  But, the output shows `OrderedDict([('sharperatio', 0.19697863771541763)])`.

Comment: What does `print(sqn)` shows?

Comment: `print(sqn)` shows 3.14 (a different metric altogether).

Comment: Then what outputs the `OrderedDict` in your program?

Comment: `the_strategy.analyzers.my_sharpe.get_analysis()`.  The docs are at https://www.backtrader.com/docu/analyzers/analyzers/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution worked:

```
list(the_strategy.analyzers._sharpe.get_analysis().values())[0]
```